# Changing Date in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, date

How can I change the date in magento 2? Not the format, but the date.

For example, I want to post some article with the date of a week ago, like 20 march. How can I do this?

I have searched for it but I can't find it. I can only find for the format.

Comment: well, you have to change in db in respective table unless there is option to set date in the form which you are using for article posting.

Answer (score 0):

Magento out of the box doesn't have a blog feature. So you need to see what extension you are using for posting an article. Then you need to go to the database table for that extension and change the value for the publishing time for that post. For example, if you are using Magefan you need to change the value for publish_time in the magefan_blog_post.

Answer (score 0):

You ca try something like the following,

```
$date = date_create("2018-03-20");
echo date_format($date,"Y-m-d");
```